# Updating database with jEditable & mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, jeditable

First of all, jEditable works for me - I can enter a value, hit enter and enjoy the sight of the new value in the table. However, this value is never inserted into the database. 
As far as I understand, the jQuery code from the jEditable website

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
 });
```

which I have changed to link to my update.php script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$value = $_POST['value'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

echo $value;

$updateTest=$conn->query("UPDATE table SET column='".$value."' WHERE ID='".$id."'");
```

should update the database, but nothing happens. When I look at the network log function of Firefox, I can see that there is no ID submitted (I do not know where this ID is supposed to come from in the first place, there is nothing in the example), but the value is there. There does not seem to be a response from the server, however.

Maybe the table itself is the problem:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$ID = $row["ID"];

print '<tr>';
print '<td><div class="edit" data-pk="'.$ID.'">'.$row["column"].'</div></td>';
print '</tr>';
```

(I left out the SELECT statement because everything else is displayed correctly)

Sadly, there is no explanation why the div should have an id - it's apparently not what is submitted in the POST request.

I have googled around a bit, but I could not find an answer to this. It's probably obvious, but I just can't find it. Ever since I changed my original prepared statement to this I don't get errors anymore, either.

I would be very grateful for any help, especially if you could explain my mistake to me so I won't repeat it in the future.

---

If there is any place on the internet with an actual complete (mysqli) example of what the save.php file mentioned in the Jeditable documentation looks like and you have the link (I certainly didn't find  it...), I'd take that too.

Comment: First, **use prepared statements**! Second, the `id` should be in `pk` (which stands for `primary key`). Third, your element needs to have the attribute `data-pk` set. Forth, remove that `id`. That's invalid HTML, since `id` values can't be just a number.

Comment: Well my goal is to return to a prepared statement once I get this to work. And I never realized ids can't be numbers, I normally use classes for everything, that's great to know. Anyway, that's some very useful information, I'll try it, thanks! But.. where would I put `pk`? Is that what you mean with `data-pk`?

Comment: In HTML5, `id` *can* be a number https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov Sorry then. I guess I should have read that before speaking. Dang, I have so much broken code now!

Comment: Technically, you were correct, but according to the 4.01 spec :)

Comment: ...Uh, data-pk is not set in the HTML, is it? I really don't understand jQuery very well.

Comment: Dude, sorry for giving you wrong info. Actually, it reads the element's id. I've read the documentation and found it. But I've seen your mistake. You have `UPDATE table SET[...]` and `table` is a reserved word and will fail. Change your query to `UPDATE my_table SET column='".$value."' WHERE ID='".$id."'` (or use backticks around the table name).

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov The 4.01 spec on `id` attributes makes a lot more sense and helps to keep all `id`s unique.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is just a placeholder. it's called "sugar" :|

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
print '<td><div class="edit" data-pk="'.ID.'">'.$row["column"].'</div></td>';
                                        ^^
```

There's no `$`, so `ID` is an undefined constant. PHP will probably try to be polite and assume you meant `'ID'` isntead (a string containing the letters `I` and `D`), which means ALL of your rows are going to show up in the client as `data-pk=ID`, and not `data-pk=1`, `data-pk=2`, etc...

Comment: oh yes, that is a typo in the example. Fixing that now.

Answer (score 0):

As there seems to be no solution to this (or, more precisely, I'm running out of time for this project), I switched to modals. If anyone comes across this and considers modals a viable option, here's what I've done:

I'm using a GET form and an update page that updates different tables depending on which page the request comes from - that's what "ref" is for.

update.php:

```
$updateID=$_GET['id']; 
$updateRef=$_GET['ref'];

$col1=$_GET['col1'];
$col2=$_GET['col2'];

if($updateRef == "refpage"){
    $updateTable=$conn->query("UPDATE my_table SET col1='".$col1."', col2='".$col2."' WHERE ID='".$updateID."'");
    header("Location: refpage.php");
    die();
}
```

My modals are generated with the table rows, which is probably the ugliest solution anyone ever used for anything, but it works... (Can't display the form in a table, though, because tables within divs within tables are a terrible idea.)

```
$results = $conn->query("SELECT col1, col2 ID FROM my_table");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ID = $row["ID"];
    $modalID = $modalID + 1;

    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row["col1"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["col2"].'</td>';
    print '<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal'.$modalID.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="float: right !important"></span></a></td>';
    print '</tr>';

    echo '<div class="modal fade" id="editModal'.$modalID.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title">Delete</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="update.php" method="get">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            col1:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" value="'.$row["col1"].'" id="col1" name="col1" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            col2:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" value="'.$row["col2"].'" id="col2" name="col2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="ref" name="ref" value="refpage" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$ID.'" />
        <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="Update" />
    </form>

    </div>          
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>';}
```

Hope this helps someone. And in case anyone has an idea what was wrong with my original idea, I'd be happy to read the answer. I still think in place updates would be much cooler.